# Error in nodejs with npm incomplete log

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, cmder

I have a problem in cmder when I run nodejs -(in f: drive not c: drive)- 
I wrote `node -v` command and `npm -v` command, but I get an error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-06T23_03_58_306Z-debug.log
```

Maybe it's about where its receive or store?

Comment: Have you tried using npm with an administrative command prompt?

Comment: hello .... 
yes i try this but its the same . maybe cause nmp store in c drive and nodejs in f drive 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-06T23_03_58_306Z-debug.log